# How to Automatic points in Excel cell?

Tags: excel, formula, point, cells

i want to get an automatic points like this .. i dont know how !!
to add points automatically with two or three digits like this 
when enter without pressing point (Dot).

```
63.032
63.032
62.937
62.646
59.693
63.032
62.786
63.130
62.452
63.081
59.988
63.326
```

Comment: Are those thousand separators or decimal points?

Comment: A very, _very_ hacky approach could be to fill in your data without a decimal point, and use a cell formula (in the next cell) to divide the value by 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automatically insert a decimal point with three decimals, then click File > Options > Advanced, tick the box and set the number.

Note that this setting will then apply to all numbers that you enter from then onwards, in all workbooks.

[image]

If you only want to add three decimals in a specific range of the worksheet, you can use a Worksheet_Change event. The following code will monitor all cells in column A. If a whole number ( a number without a decimal ) is entered, the macro will divide the value by 1000, which effectively sets a decimal point and three decimal digits.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cel As Range
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each cel In Target
        If cel.Value = Int(cel.Value) Then cel.Value = cel.Value / 1000
    Next cel
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's all or nothing. How is Excel supposed to know if you want the decimals or not? The only other way is VBA with a Change event that monitors only specific cells.

Comment: I added an alternative with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a cell formatting option.
Press CTRL+1 to open the cell formatting dialog, and select the following options:

[image]

Comment: The dot is the decimal point in English speaking countries. What you describe is the thousand separator, which would be a comma.

Comment: That's why I asked that in my comment. Upon not receiving an answer, I gave it a shot. Since he stated "not pressing dot", I ruled out a decimal point. I couldn't imagine he would want to add _every_ number as three-digit-decimal.

Comment: Das Tausenderzeichen wird nie manuell eingegeben. Der Dezimalltrenner dagegen schon!. Die Option, die ich in meiner Antwort zeige hilft genau diesen Tastendruck einzusparen. Das wird von Leuten die viele Zahlen eingeben so oft verlangt, dass Microsoft dazu eigens eine Option eingerichtet hat.